# How to add a surcharge in Shopware 6 that considers discounts?

Tags: shopware6

So by following this guide one can add a discount/surcharge to the cart:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-discounts

So my processor looks like the following:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SurchargePlugin\Core\Checkout\Cart;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Cart;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartBehavior;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartProcessorInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\CartDataCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\LineItem;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\LineItemCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Price\AbsolutePriceCalculator;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Price\Struct\AbsolutePriceDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Rule\LineItemRule;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class ProductConfiguratorProcessor implements CartProcessorInterface
{
    public const SURCHARGE_LINE_ITEM_TYPE = 'my_surcharge';

    private AbsolutePriceCalculator $calculator;

    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(AbsolutePriceCalculator $calculator, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param CartDataCollection $data
     * @param Cart $original
     * @param Cart $toCalculate
     * @param SalesChannelContext $context
     * @param CartBehavior $behavior
     * @return void
     */
    public function process(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, Cart $toCalculate, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
    {
        $products = $this->findSurchargeProducts($toCalculate);

        // no surcharge products found? early return
        if ($products->count() === 0) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $surchargeLineItem = $this->createSurcharge($product);

            // declare price definition to define how this price is calculated
            $definition = new AbsolutePriceDefinition(
                10,
                new LineItemRule(LineItemRule::OPERATOR_EQ, $products->getKeys())
            );

            $surchargeLineItem->setPriceDefinition($definition);

            // calculate price
            $surchargeLineItem->setPrice(
                $this->calculator->calculate($definition->getPrice(), $products->getPrices(), $context)
            );

            // add surcharge to new cart
            $toCalculate->add($surchargeLineItem);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param LineItem $product
     * @return LineItem
     */
    private function createSurcharge(LineItem $product): LineItem
    {
        $surchargeLineItem = new LineItem(Uuid::randomHex(), self::SURCHARGE_LINE_ITEM_TYPE, null, 1);

        $surchargeLineItem->setLabel("Surcharge");
        $surchargeLineItem->setGood(false);
        $surchargeLineItem->setStackable(true);
        $surchargeLineItem->setRemovable(false);
        $surchargeLineItem->setQuantity($product->getQuantity());

        return $surchargeLineItem;
    }
}
```

The priority in the services.xml is the following:

```xml
<tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="4500" />
```

However, this surcharge is ignored by discounts. E.g if you have a product in the cart that costs 100€. And the surcharge of 10€ is added. Afterwards you apply a 10% discount.
Only 10€ of discount is added, but I need 11€ of discount.

What am I still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CartScopeDiscountPackager` is specifically only [considering line items with the type `LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE` for the calculated discount](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Promotion/Cart/Discount/ScopePackager/CartScopeDiscountPackager.php#L34). Hence why your line item with your custom type is out of scope.

You can write a decorator to add your line item to the discount package.

```xml
<service id="SurchargePlugin\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\ScopePackager\CartScopeDiscountPackagerDecorator"
         decorates="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\ScopePackager\CartScopeDiscountPackager">
    <argument type="service" id="SurchargePlugin\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\ScopePackager\CartScopeDiscountPackagerDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

```php
namespace SurchargePlugin\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\ScopePackager;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Cart;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\Group\LineItemQuantity;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\LineItem;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\DiscountLineItem;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\DiscountPackage;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\DiscountPackageCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\Discount\DiscountPackager;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use SurchargePlugin\Core\Checkout\Cart\ProductConfiguratorProcessor;

class CartScopeDiscountPackagerDecorator extends DiscountPackager
{
    public function __construct(private readonly DiscountPackager $decorated)
    {
    }

    public function getDecorated(): DiscountPackager
    {
        return $this->decorated;
    }

    public function getMatchingItems(DiscountLineItem $discount, Cart $cart, SalesChannelContext $context): DiscountPackageCollection
    {
        $collection = $this->decorated->getMatchingItems($discount, $cart, $context);

        $surcharges = $cart->getLineItems()->filter(
            fn (LineItem $lineItem) => $lineItem->getType() === ProductConfiguratorProcessor::SURCHARGE_LINE_ITEM_TYPE
        );

        $discountItems = $collection->getAllLineMetaItems();

        foreach ($surcharges as $surcharge) {
            $discountItems->add(new LineItemQuantity(
                $surcharge->getId(),
                1
            ));
        }

        if ($discountItems->count() === 0) {
            return new DiscountPackageCollection([]);
        }

        return new DiscountPackageCollection([new DiscountPackage($discountItems)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, by calling `$cart->getLineItems()` in the `CartScopeDiscountPackagerDecorator` I am only getting the LineItem of type `LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE`. My `ProductConfiguratorProcessor::SURCHARGE_LINE_ITEM_TYPE` is not showing up. Do you know why?

Comment: The priority of your processor is too low, it runs after `PromotionProcessor` which has a priority of `4900`. Set yours to something slightly higher, like `4901`.